# Check if string contains any of the following

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to check if a string contains one of four sub strings in a simpler way than this:

```dart
if (imageUrl.contains('.jpg') || 
        imageUrl.contains('.png') || 
        imageUrl.contains('.tif') || 
        imageUrl.contains('.gif')) {
    }
```

Is there a way to do this? For example checking against a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegularExpression can solve your problem. RegEx are used to search patterns in strings.
RegEx example:

```
^The        matches any string that starts with The
end$        matches a string that ends with end
^The end$   exact string match (starts and ends with The end)
abc*        matches a string that has ab followed by zero or more c
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex pattern instead of a simple string:

```
imageUrl.contains(new RegExp("\.(jpg|png|tif|gif)"))
```

Might be somewhat simpler.